# What if parameter greyed out when using active relationships

Tags: powerbi

Does anyone know why the what if parameter button is greyed out when using active relationships in Power Bi? I have an active relationship between two of my tables and the button is greyed out. When I deactivate the relationship, save and close the file and then re open the file, the button is no longer greyed out. Obviously I want to be able to have the connection between the two tables active though!

Comment: What kinds of connections do you have (import/DirectQuery/Live)? Can you include a screenshot of your model diagram?

Comment: Sorry for the delay. The data was simply imported from excel. I may be able to include a screenshot when I return to work